# If a terrain size is larger than the maximum limit (i.e. 1024 tiles) of Navmesh / gridgraph, how to apply grid graph/Navmesh?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to apply a Navmesh graph on the terrain, it says

> "tile count: 3025 exceeds maximum limit 1024".

What can I do to increase the maximum limit of 1024, or is there another way in which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the maximum limit is, to the best of my knowledge, not an option. Try increasing the [Radius setting](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Navmeshbaking.html) of your Navmesh. That should lower the tile count.

If those results are not acceptable, you'd have to consider splitting up your environment into sub-sections I guess.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit, I have just increase radius to 0 to 6 by guess and it applied. How to calculate precise radius for any terrain. And would it effect anything else if the radius size is greater than the required??

Answer (score 0):

You may increase Radius in Bake options, but often bake results with big radius are not acceptable. In this case you may remove "Navigation Static" checkmark in Navigation->Object from some big meshes that are not parts of your character walk path. For example remove fields/forest/street or other decoration meshes around your walkable road from navigation static. This will free a lot of navigation mesh tiles for your character's playable area